# How well does Cocoa allow auditing of I/O to USB, FireWire and optical media on a Mac?

Tags: mac-osx, usb, audit, dtrace, firewire

I have a client who wants us to lock down the Mac laptops we're using to access his data.  He wants an audit of all files read and written from removable media (USB, FireWire, optical).  I have [a sister question](https://serverfault.com/questions/211444/looking-for-a-way-to-audit-monitor-removable-media-on-a-mac) re: finding a commercial app for this, but I'm starting to feel like the only fun^H^H^H suitable solution will be DIY.

Does Cocoa have an API to audit the bus/device, any identifiers (S/N, vendorID, et.al.), the filesystem metadata (stat()) and blocks in/out, etc.?  Does dtrace do this!?

*I could reinstall every laptop with ZFS and mirror any external device via copy-on-write...*

Answer (score 1):

You might also take a look at the [FSEvents API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289), although I think this only tracks writes, not reads.